# Is it good practice to update R packages often?

Tags: r

I've started to use R a little while ago and am not sure how often to update the installed packages (at this time, I'm using mostly ggplot2 and rattle). One one hand it's the typical geek impulse to have the latest version :-) On the other, updates can break functionality and, as an R beginner, I don't want to waste time looking into package incompatibilities and reinstalling libraries, it's almost certain I wouldn't notice any difference with an improved package.

With other applications I have a sense developed from experience on how often to upgrade, how much to wait between the release of an upgrade and installing it and so on. But I'm in the dark with regards to R.

And to be clear: I'm not talking about R itself, but its libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my philosophy: the naïve user never updates. The sophisticated user always updates. The power user updates often, but carefully.

Mindless updating is not always beneficial. Bugs work their way in updated versions of R libraries (or R itself!), and you could break your existing code by updating without reading the change log or commit history. For example, R 2.11 broke `lme4` on OS X... it pays to carefully update and run demos of packages between releases. It really sucks to update to a new library or R release and realize something broke when you have a deadline.

Comment: That's why you have rollbacks provided by the `Archive/` directories on CRAN.

Comment: Yes, but checking beforehand is a lot less effort than rolling back.

Comment: Let me know where you park the time machine that tells ex-ante what would have broken had you installed the package(s).

Comment: It's called Google. Unless everyone literally updates to the newest release of R (or a package) at the exact same time, chances are someone has had an issue and sent it to the R mailing list. Being aware of issues helps. I really don't see how Googling releases/issues or looking at change logs before updating is a bad practice.

Comment: Also, upgrade only one or few packages at a time. It makes it more difficult to find where the bug is coming from if you just updated 50 packages and something is not working (not impossible, just more difficult).

Comment: You guys astonish me. What ever happened to "release early, release often"?  As a CRAN author I am stunned by this.  Oh well, chacun a son gout.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: Dirk, sometimes you just can't afford that. A while ago I updated some packages, and everything seemed to work well. Then my boss asked me to analyse some new data, so I opened an R script I use for this task and it wasn't working anymore. The problem was with one of the packages I updated (`tcltk`). I managed to analyse the data without that script, but still, it was annoying. I'm more of a "update often, if you're not in the middle of analysing data for a paper" kind of person.

Answer (score 12):

Yes it is.

Why exactly would you want to hang on to old bugs and lacking features?

Comment: Well, one reason is that sometimes a new release introduces new bugs and breaks features. I'm less concerned about esoteric features (which I'm not going to use) but more about package dependencies. If library X depends on Y v3.1 and upgrade Y to v3.2, is it possible for X to not work at all any more? Much like the "DLL hell" in Windows?

Comment: CRAN has rigorous testing. You can trust it. This is one of the reasons it has been successful.

Comment: Great then, I wasn't very aware about their testing. Thanks.

Comment: @Dirk: While I agree with your answer, I would also add that CRAN's testing mostly addresses the formatting/structure of the package (which should catch OS issues, etc.); it doesn't (it couldn't) enforce anything about the content.  Actually testing that falls to the package author, and there is an immense amount of variability there.

Comment: I continue to disagree rather strongly. In 10+ years of CRAN use I don't think I have been bitten once by something that was truly harming other components. The overall bug rate is very low. In fact, I think so highly of it that I helped (twice) to build a robot to turn all packages into .deb package (now at [cran2deb](http://debian.cran.r-project.org). I also immediately update the `r-cran-*` Debian (source) packages I look after. But maybe that is because upgrades are more robust on my OS of choice than on the other two leading consumer brands. Shrug.

Comment: Actually I have coworkers who very intentionally don't update regularly, if they're in the middle of a project.  Changing the version of R or packages could cause conflicting results.  Mind you this isn't the case when there's an overt bug (e.g. gcrma a couple of years ago), but there's a strong need to keep the environment stable during a project.

Comment: The question was NOT about R so let's stay on topic here.  But in that context I note the desperation of R Core who offer alpha, beta and rc releases --- which seemingly nobody cares to touch. Yet then everybody swarms in and complains about bugs once the .0 version is released.  I have the feeling people want to eat their cake and have it too: free open source software that is bug free yet insist on not participating in finding bugs.  See a problem here?

Comment: What I'm referring to in my comment are instances such as when the formatting of an object changes (for instance), where a column name has changed or a field is removed.  I have experienced this, and it has broken dependencies for me; it was caught in my own unit tests and I could resolve it fairly quickly, but it's not something that I think you should do in a production environment without testing your own dependencies first.  This doesn't relate to OS issues, but to package specific content.  So, I agree that upgrading often is the right thing to do, but just add "with your own testing".

Comment: I am somewhat with you on "production" environments. However, that was NOT a conditioning variable in the original question which was on the general context of R usage.  And there upgrades are good for you in general.  Particular cases may require particular treatment.

Comment: Dirk:  I said "R or packages".  See my other response.  I work with people who need to keep their R environment (and *that includes packages*) stable for the duration of a project.

Comment: I'll also note it took me a long time to get used to that practice, coming from RG's group where if you weren't working with the latest checkout of everything something was wrong with you :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and yes, I am in the same camp as the Hutch folks :)

Answer (score 5):

The question is already answered, but I'll offer my 2 cents.  In an organization, updating R should be treated like updating `gcc` or `Java`: with warnings, with a staging area, a rollback plan, etc.  Others' work and results may be affected.  [See update #2]

I am more impulsive about updating R packages.  As long as you can reproduce the state of your system at any point in time, there's little to worry about.  Ensuring that nightly backups occur should be the domain of your sysadmin.

The basic idea is that you should be able to reproduce everything.  Actually testing that your earlier results are reproduced is dependent on whether you want to disprove your assumption that there are no bugs or changes that will affect later results.  :)

---

Update 1.  As has been mentioned in comments and above, updating in a production environment or any environment where stability is optimal (e.g. bugs are either known or not significant), introducing new bugs, new dependencies, different output, or any variety of other software regressions, should be done quite carefully.  Moreover, where you're updating from matters a lot.  Updating from R-Forge is more likely to expose you to the newest bugs than from CRAN.  Even so, I have found and reported bugs that persisted through 3+ versions of a package on CRAN, as well as other regressions that have just magically appeared.  I test a lot, but updating, finding new bugs, and debugging is an effort that I don't always want to (or have time to) undertake.

I am reminded of this question after finding a new bug in a new version of a package that I use a lot.  Just to check, I reverted to an earlier version - no more crashes, though tracking down the cause took a couple of hours, because I assumed it was not arising in this package.  I'll send a note to the maintainer before long, so others won't have to stumble on the same bug.

Update 2.  In an organization, I have to say that the answer is no.  In fact, in any case where there may be two or more concurrent instances of R, it is very unwise to blindly update the packages while another may be using them.  There are likely to be good methods for [hot-swapping packages, I just don't yet know them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026443/safe-method-for-updating-r-packages-is-hot-swapping-possible).  Keep in mind that the two instances need only share libraries (i.e. where the packages are stored), and, AFAIK, need not run concurrently on the same machine.  Thus, if libraries are placed on shared systems, e.g. over NFS, one may not know where else R is running at the same time, using those libraries.  Accidentally killing another R process is not usually a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless you have a good reason not to (see my comment to Dirk)

Comment: Where you missed was the original question was about.

Comment: @Dirk, in @geoffjentry's defense he did state "Changing the version of R **or packages** could cause conflicting results..." That may have been an ex post edit, but it does not seem totally off base.

Comment: Dirk - if you're not updating your R, you are unlikely to be updating versions of packages, particularly with things like BioC where BioC releases are directly tied to R releases.  Also, not updating their packages is the primary reason they're not updating.

Answer (score 1):

Although some of the following has been mentioned in previous answers, I think it might be beneficial to make a few things explicit. As a developer, I think that updating packages often (and R-devel for the matter), is a good practice. You definitely want to stick with the latest out there. If your package imports/depends/sugests... interacts with other packages, you want to ensure interoperability on day to day basis, and not face the 'bugs' just before release, when time is short.
On the other hand, some environments will put special emphasis on exact reproducibility. In that case, one may want to adopt a more careful strategy with updating.

But it is worth emphasising that these two behaviours are not exclusive. It is possible to install different versions of R and maintain different [libraries](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-is-the-difference-between-pac%5Ckage-and-library_003f), to benefit from a bleeding edge development environment and a more stable one for production.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for two versions of R/libraries in parallel. As an open-source user, it should be your duty to test the software. As a professional, you should have something robust to work with. Package devtools introduced a dev_mode to ease the switch between the two modes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to respond **as often as you need to, and never when you're in a hurry**!

Firstly, debate the chances that you're labouring under a bug of which you are unaware. I would moot that is quite rare. If you're suffering under a bug and there's a newer version in which the bug is fixed, plan an upgrade. If you want a new feature, plan an upgrade. If it's your first day back after Christmas and the biggest overhead is trying to remember what you were actually doing last then the overhead of messing about with some new dependency requirements (which may include system components outside of R) is probably relatively small, so consider seeing what updates are available (guess what I did today) ;-)

The **golden rule** is probably that there isn't a single, recommended schedule other than what makes sense for your use; daily updates will inevitably result in fewer updates each time and thus minimize the pain of the actual update, but it's not worth it if you constantly get different numerical results from one day to the next because of some change to how a function does sampling (different numerical results have plagued Coursera students using caret). Don't underestimate the value of a stable system that allows you to just get on with productive work rather than faffing.